# Drop and "Create Table as Select" (CTaS) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Could you explain some DBA guys advise to not use CTaS then drop table repeatedly lots of time? Whether it impacts to data dictionary in Oracle.

Comment: What did those DBA guys say when you asked them?

Comment: Why do you think creating and dropping tables at run-time is a *good* idea? Have you considered using [a global temporary table](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/tables.htm#GUID-A48CB362-FC15-4A26-8386-906A55F6788E) instead? [Also see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6957713/266304).

Comment: They said that CTaS negatively affect:
-          Oracle dictionary 
-          Replication to backup database; and as @AlexPoole said, they also tell that I should use Global temporary table and truncate instead of CTAS and drop... I just want to know how it impact .

Answer (score 0):

it impacts the undo . Also if database is in archive log mode 
lot of archvie logs gets created .
If archive space is filled datbase can crash.

Answer (score 0):

Also in the newer versions of Oracle dropped tables sit in the Recycle Bin unless you do DROP TABLE . PURGE or some such.